# Is it possible to have one event handler attached to different components in React?

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to have one event handler for different components in React? Just like you would have in .NET for different buttons you could have one even handler that will handle the click event.

If that is possible, how would you capture who fired the event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<button onClick={this.handleChange}/>

handleChange = ({ target }) => {
  const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
  const name = target.name;

  this.setState({
    [name]: value
  });
}
```

This should handle most of the scenarios for different inputs. Hope that helps!!

Comment: question: why do you put name in square brackets [name] or is it because it is reserved word?

Comment: var c = {[a]: "d"} is syntactic sugar for var c = {}; c[a] = "d"

Answer (score 0):

You can always bind the same handler to different components.

```
render() {
    return (
        <button
            onClick={this.handler}
        />
    );
}

handler = (event) => {
    let target = event.target;
    // do whatever
}
```

`event.target` would tell you which element is being clicked on.